# Split large file based on column value - linux

Tags: linux, awk

I wanted to split the large file (185 Million records) to more than one files based on one column value.The file is .dat file and the delimiter used inbetween the columns are ^A (\u0001).

The File content is like this:

```
194^A1^A091502^APR^AKIMBERLY^APO83^A^A^A^A0183^AUSA^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A
194^A1^A091502^APR^AJOHN^APO83^A^A^A^A0183^AUSA^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A
194^A^A091502^APR^AASHLEY^APO83^A^A^A^A0183^AUSA^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A
194^A3^A091502^APR^APETER^APO83^A^A^A^A0183^AUSA^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A
194^A4^A091502^APR^AJOE^APO83^A^A^A^A0183^AUSA^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A
```

now i wanted to split the file based on second column value, if you see the third row the second column value is empty, so all the empty rows should come one file , remaining all should come one file.

Please help me on this. I tried to google, it seems we should use awk for this.

Regards,
Shankar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk -F '\x01' '$2 == "" { print > "empty.dat"; next } { print > "normal.dat" }' filename
```

The file names can be chosen arbitrarily, of course. `print > "file"` prints the current record to a file named `"file"`.

**Addendum re: comment:** Removing the column is a little trickier but certainly feasible. I'd use

```
awk -F '\x01' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { fname = $2 == "" ? "empty.dat" : "normal.dat"; for(i = 2; i < NF; ++i) $i = $(i + 1); --NF; print > fname }' filename
```

This works as follows:

```
BEGIN {                                          # output field separator is
  OFS = FS                                       # the same as input field
                                                 # separator, so that the
                                                 # rebuilt lines are formatted
                                                 # just like they came in
}
{
  fname = $2 == "" ? "empty.dat" : "normal.dat"  # choose file name

  for(i = 2; i < NF; ++i) {                      # set all fields after the
    $i = $(i + 1)                                # second back one position
  }

  --NF                                           # let awk know the last field
                                                 # is not needed in the output

  print > fname                                  # then print to file.
}
```

Comment: `awk -F '\x01'  '{ print > ($2 == ""?"empty":"normal")".dat"}'`

Comment: That'll also work, but I don't think it's clearer. YMMV.

Comment: Was gonna post as an answer but it was too similar to yours so i thought ii'd just add as alternative in the comments :)

Comment: @Wintermute: is it possible to drop that column(the column value which we are checking) in the output files?

Comment: That takes a little more doing, but yes. See the edit.

Comment: @Wintermute: Is awk support more than one files as input? because i have more than one files but all are same layout.. please do let me know.. can we pass * instead of filename at the end?

Comment: @Wintermute i would like to know the code you given is for removing second field or last field? i wanted to remove the second field not the last field in the output.

Comment: It's for the second. To remove the last, shifting back the fields would not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Wintermute .. But its taking lot of time to split a file with 185 Million records.. is there anyway we can improve the performance?

Comment: How much is "a lot of time"? I'd honestly be surprised if the awk code takes up most of the time in this (it's going to be disk I/O). A file with 185 million records has to be somewhere around 10GB, based on the line length you showed -- that's not something you crunch in a second. The way to improve performance, I suspect, is to have the file on an SSD.

Comment: @Wintermute the file size 50 GB and its taking about 30 minutes to process 185 Million. I will check my disk is SSD or HDD. Thanks a lot.

Comment: On the off-chance that the field shifting really is the bottleneck, you could try `awk -F '\x01' '{ fname = $2 == "" ? "empty.dat" : "normal.dat"; sub(/\x01[^\x01]*/, ""); print > fname }'`.